# Проблема с иcпользованием Android Intents в встроенном браузере Gmail

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

Есть на обычной странице кнопки социальных сетей где пользователь нажимает кнопку и соответственно идет шаринг в соц.сети. Всё это делается для Android и я  использую Android Intent для Хрома на примере вот этого(HTML): `<a href="intent://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250152/what-is-the-intent-to-launch-any-website-link-in-google-chrome#Intent;scheme=http;end">` 
Это даёт нам следующее: когда пользователь щелкает у себя на смартфоне на кнопку, открывается выбор, с помощью какого установленного на телефоне приложения открыть ссылку. Во внешних браузерах типа Google Chrome , Opera , Firefox ссылку открывает нормально и предоставляет пользователю выбор приложения, но есть такая штука, как встроенный браузер в Gmail и если в нём клацнуть на кнопку то перенаправления не происходит!! Это WebView не поддерживает Intent??? Как можно решить данную проблему? Спасибо!